# C99 standard: is the logical negation operator defined to also operate directly on a function?

Tags: c, syntax, negation

I am curious if there is any difference between assigning the output of a function `foo()` to a variable and then prefixing the logical negation `!` operator vs. prefixing the logical negation operator directly before the function. i.e. is

```
int output = foo();
if(!output){

}
```

formally equivalent to:

```
if(!foo()) {

}
```

Comment: It's not operating on the function unless you did `!foo` which is pointless (unless `foo` is a function pointer), if not illegal.

Comment: Logical negation "operates" on an *expression*, the source of which is irrelevant, so long as the expression eval result is of a type to which the operator can be applied.

Comment: If the function is `int foo()` then it is identical. The negation isn't operating on a function (see title) but on the output of a function.

Comment: @WeatherVane — it doesn't matter if the function returns an integer type, or a floating point type, or a pointer: as long as it returns a scalar value (rather than a structure), then the `!` operator will evaluate whether the result is zero (`0`, `0.0`, `NULL`) and return true (integer `1`) if it is and false (integer `0`) if not — the result type is `int`.  See also C11 [§6.5.3.3 Unary arithmetic operators ¶5](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.3.3p5).  I suppose that if the function returns a type longer than `int`, the value could be truncated on assignment and might produce zero.

Comment: @FiddlingBits If `foo` is the name of a function, then _any use_ of `foo`, other than applying the function-call operator to it, will first implicitly convert it to a pointer to the function.  In a strictly conforming program, it is not possible for the name of a function to evaluate to a null pointer, therefore `(!foo)` will always be false.  However, some compilers have an extension that allows specific functions to not be defined at runtime (often called "weak symbols") so that doesn't necessarily generalize to _all_ C programs.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler If the conversion of the return value of `foo` to an `int` results in the value `0`, the behaviour will be different between the two snippets. If `foo` returns a `float` with the value `0.1`, then `!output` will be `1`, but `!foo()` will be `0`.

Comment: @ThomasJager: yes, that's what I realized before I typed the "I suppose …" part of the comment.

Comment: This isn't specific to the `!` operator. All operators work the same when the argument is an expression or a variable that was set from the same expression. The only thing you may need to worry about is operator precedence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probably isn't what you're thinking of, but it *is* a difference between your two example code fragments, and an important one: in

```
int output = foo();
if (!output) {
   ...
}
...
```

the variable `output`, and therefore the value returned from the function, is available to code both inside and below the if-statement.  In your other example, the value returned from the function is not available to anything but the `!` operator inside the if-condition.

This is probably the most important practical reason to choose one form or the other; do you *need* that value for anything besides the if-condition?  If so, you need the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Other than the difference mentioned by @zwol, there is no logical difference.  The expression `! foo()` is processed as "call foo()" then "negate the return value".

Doing `output = foo();` then `! output` does "call foo()" then "save the return value in variable output" then "negate the value in output".  Same result.

In fact, a compiler might optimize away the variable `output` - depending on the context.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info! It's interesting to know what's happening behind the scene with the machine code.

Comment: `output = foo();` does not do "save the return value in variable output". It converts the return value to the type of `output` and saves that, and that conversion can cause differences from `!foo()`.